# Interpret any date from any string

Tags: excel, vba

I have various formats of dates, in strings, all in ColumnA.  Here is a small example.

```
-rw-r--r--   35 30067    10224     <-- 2018-09
-rw-r--r--   36 30067    10224     <-- 2018-09
-rw-r--r--   65 30067    10224     <-- 2018-10-24
```

Is there a way I can interpret any date from any given string?

Comment: Looks like you can handle this by extensions using a switch, e.g., case 1 --> right(path,4) = .zip --> left(right(path,11),1) = yr, etc.  A bit of work to set-up, but it appears you are consistent in the naming conventions.  That's at least 1 option.

Comment: Some formats can be handled but you may get false positives as well... for example.. `GMD_ASE1JPN_ID_181031--- 2018-10-31` what in case of `GMD_ASE1JPN_ID_181019`. Is this 18/10/2019 or 19/10/2018?

Comment: It's always Year-Month-Day.

Comment: How come the first two rows you want returned `2018-09`?  And then later on `2018-09-28`? I get the second and third, `20181024` into `2018-10-24`, but where'd you divine the dates for those without such a format?

Comment: Could you please explain the date translations where the translated date seems to be in the month prior to the actual date.  And what do you mean by different formats?  Seems to me all the dates are in the same format of `mmm-dd`

Comment: Right, basically the same format; Y-M-D or Y-M (for monthly files).  I just meant, there are lots of different formats of strings.  All dates are the same format.  Some are daily and some are monthly (could be the last day of the month or last business day of the month; doesn't matter).  So, for ASE1LXJP1809.BET, I would be happy to just get 2018-09.  Monthly files don't have days; only Y-M.

Comment: Yes, but that file shows `Oct 1` as the date.  How are you converting that to 2018-09  which would be September and not October.  Some of your conversions seem to subtract 1 day, others more than one day from the date shown.

Comment: Whoops! ASE1181022.RATE  <-- 2018-10-19 is actually 2018-10-22
Also, GMD_ASE2L_100_UnadjCov_181129.zip  <-- 2018-11-28 is actually 2018-11-28.  I typed those in manually.  This is almost impossible for a person to do.  I need some kind of algo to do the work.  I'll update my original post, so it represents things correctly.

Comment: You have four different date formats in your data, and two different formats for your output.  I would suggest using VBA and possibly regular expressions to extract and analyze the date format; then convert it to a "real date" and finally, output the value as a string in the desired format.

Comment: Is your year all the same as 2018?

Comment: firs line, **Oct 01 16:37** Is the character irrelevant to the date you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get date with regular expression. As far as I see, the date is either in the end of the string or there's a dot after it (followed by extension). The regex takes into account the length of the year: either 4 or 2. Also it manages the case when month is expressed in text. *Important!* When the day is absent, I set it as first day.

```
Function GetDate(strString$)
    Dim sYear$, sMonth$, sDay$
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True: .Pattern = "(\d{2})([a-z]{3}|\d{2})(\d{2})?(?=\.|$)"
        With .Execute(strString)
            If .Count > 0 Then
                With .Item(0)
                    sYear = .SubMatches(0)
                    sMonth = .SubMatches(1)
                    sDay = .SubMatches(2)
                    sYear = "20" & sYear
                    If Not IsNumeric(sMonth) Then
                        sMonth = GetMonthIndex(sMonth)
                    End If
                    If Len(sDay) = 0 Then sDay = "01"
                    GetDate = DateSerial(CInt(sYear), CInt(sMonth), CInt(sDay))
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Function

Private Function GetMonthIndex$(strMonth$)
    Select Case strMonth
        Case "Jan": GetMonthIndex = "01"
        Case "Feb": GetMonthIndex = "02"
        Case "Mar": GetMonthIndex = "03"
        Case "Apr": GetMonthIndex = "04"
        Case "May": GetMonthIndex = "05"
        Case "Jun": GetMonthIndex = "06"
        Case "Jul": GetMonthIndex = "07"
        Case "Aug": GetMonthIndex = "08"
        Case "Sep": GetMonthIndex = "09"
        Case "Nov": GetMonthIndex = "10"
        Case "Oct": GetMonthIndex = "11"
        Case "Dec": GetMonthIndex = "12"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I tested your code. some rows occur error.(rows 6-13 in above example)

Comment: @Dy.Lee OK. I'll take a look.

Comment: I don't test your code, yet.But your code is beautiful.

Comment: Works perfect JohnnyL!!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Simple one liner for your `GetMonthIndex function`: `GetMonthIndex = Format(CDate(strMonth & "/1 0"), "mm")` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim vS As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim s As String

    Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB = rngDB

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To r
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        vS = Split(s, ".")
        If IsNumeric(vS(1)) Then
            s = vS(1)
            s = Right(s, 6)
            s = Left(s, 2) & " " & Mid(s, 3, 2) & " " & Right(s, 2)
            vR(i, 1) = DateValue(s)
        Else
            s = vS(0)
            s = Right(s, 6)
            If IsNumeric(s) Then
                s = Left(s, 2) & " " & Mid(s, 3, 2) & " " & Right(s, 2)
                vR(i, 1) = DateValue(s)
            Else
                s = Right(s, 4)
                If IsNumeric(s) Then
                    s = Left(s, 2) & " " & Mid(s, 3, 2) & " " & 1
                    vR(i, 1) = DateValue(s)
                Else
                    s = vS(0)
                    s = Right(s, 7)
                    s = Left(s, 2) & " " & Mid(s, 3, 3) & " " & Right(s, 2)
                    vR(i, 1) = DateValue(s)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Range("b1").Resize(r) = vR

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any fixed pattern it will be complicated.
The better way in your case on a logical way would by to associate date pattern to files like

- 1 => *.BUS    -> YYMM
- 2 => *.IDE    -> YYMMDD
- 3 => TTN* -> YYYYMMDD

And on the same logic get a mapping table with position of date string in the file name

- 1 => Last 4 characters of file name
- 2 => Last 6 characters of file name
- 3 => Extension

In a macro function or a SWITCH function.